# Sculptures measured in area

Tags: measure-expressions

What is the correct way to say how many square centimetres of sculptures someone created in total?
"Created a total of 65,000 suqare centimetres of sculptures" or "Created sculptures with a total surface area of 65,000 square centimetres". Which way to say it is better? Or maybe yuo know how to write it better?

Comment: The grammar and wording of your guess is correct and natural, though describing sculptures by area in square centimetres is not at all natural.

Comment: You may want to explain why you are measuring 3D objects with a 2D unit? In other words, what are you really trying to say?

Comment: Which one is correct? The first one or the second one?

Comment: I need to measure 3D object in 2D untist for some small project

Comment: Since it's highly unusual to give the surface area of sculptures, I would suggest your second version to make the meaning clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sound more natural, you may choose to add more parameters (provided you have them).

- "**Created** "n(number of)" **sculptures with** a total volume of x cubic centimetres and **a total surface area of 65,000 square centimetres** with complex curves and shapes"

Your original sentence parts are highlighted in bold. As it is highly unusual way to describe sculptures in square centimetres, making your sentence more detailed with extra parameters, will hide this unusual-ness.

Among the original two sentences, "Created sculptures with a total surface area of 65,000 square centimetres" is the better sentence as it avoids confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect.  A sculpture is a three-dimensional object, and so can't be measured in cm².

While it may be mathematically possible to measure the surface area of a sculpture in cm², it isn't a useful or meaningful measurement of the sculpture itself.  It tells you nothing about the sculpture's size, artistic qualities or the skill of the artist.

I'm trying to think of an analogy, but I can think of nothing as ridiculous as describing sculptures in terms of their area!

Moreover, 65000cm² is not an easily visualised area.  6.5m² is clearer (and mathematically equivalent)  For Americans, you should convert to square feet. So "{Someone} created sculptures with a total surface area of 6.5 square metres (or 70 square feet) This sentence needs a subject to be grammatical.